# Magento 2 - How to retrieve the products id, price, quantity on successful order placement?

Tags: event-observer, onepage-checkout, magento2.4

**My Observer Class**

```
<?php
    
    namespace GCV\GenerateCSV\Observer;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    
    class GenerateCSV implements ObserverInterface
    {
     protected $_objectManager;
     private $logger;
     private $productFactory;
    
    
      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
      ) {
          $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
          $this->logger = $logger;
          $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
      }
    
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
      {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
        $this->logger->info($order_id);
        $this->logger->info("observer working"); 
        $productIds = array();
        $product_qty = array();
        $product_price = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
        {
        $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        $product_qty[] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $product_price[] = $item->getPrice();
        $this->logger->info($productIds[$i]);
        $this->logger->info($product_qty[$i]);
        $this->logger->info($product_price[$i]);
        $i++; 
        }
    }
    }
```

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
   <event name='sales_order_place_after'>
        <observer
                name='sales_order_place_after'
                instance='GCV\GenerateCSV\Observer\GenerateCSV'
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, such as which observer you're using, what solutions have you tried, and what output are you getting on the current posted code. Mentioning small details will be more helpful to understand the issue and provide a appropriate solution

Comment: @mohit Rane: I am using the sales_order_place_after event. And with the above Observer class, I am not able to get the product price inside the foreach statement. However, I am getting product id and quantity in the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below solution

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Extensoin\Observer\OrderObserver" />
</event>
</config>
```

After that, you need to create Observer file at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\OrderObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
        $statuscode = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus();
        $statuslabel = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatusLabel();
        $products= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getAllItems()
 
  }
}
```

if works for you then please accept as a solution

Comment: what are all available in $products object? Can you be more specific? I've tried to dump the $products variable but it is giving me a timeout error.

Comment: What exactly u need..u can use foreach ($products as $item)
        { print_r($item->getData());
        }

Comment: foreach ($products as $item) { print_r($item->getData()); } I've tried this already In fact I tried var_dump() also. The problem when I try to print this data in log or checkout page, my RAM is getting full or I am visually getting an endless loop in checkout page.

Comment: Finally I am able to print the item object using `$this->logger->debug("webarro", $item->getData());` but I dont know how to extract the price, id and quantity ordered. I have tried `$this->logger->debug('ID:', $item->getData('product_id'));
    $this->logger->debug('Quantity: ', $item->getData('qty_ordered'));
    $this->logger->debug('Price: ', $item->getData('price'));` but its not working!

Comment: Whats is the output of $this->logger->debug($item->getData()); ??

Comment: Please check this http://pastie.org/p/3YdZ6swoypQToXKDCzvX1L/raw

Comment: you are getting json response so please convert json to array. use print_r(json_decode($item->getData()));

Comment: Hi Gohil, It's not `JSON` it's an array when I use `json_decode()`, I am geeting this error `main.CRITICAL: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in`

Comment: try this $WorkingArray = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);